# Replacement of values in one data frame by many csvs with allways the same structure - R

Tags: r

I need your help. I try to create a replacement of values in each column of one `data.frame` by a CSV file with always the same structure. The CSV files have the same filename as the `columnnames` in the first `data.frame`. I used the following code but it complains about the `by.x` object was not found or something. What am I doing wrong? Or do you have a better approach to my problem?

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")

path ="C:/.../"

files <- list.files(path)

dfList <- lapply(files, function(i) {
df <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, col.names=c("Column 0", "Column 1"))
name = substr(i,1,nchar(i)-5)
jointdataset <-merge (knime.in, df, by.x =eval(parse(text = name)), by.y ='Column 0')
return(jointdataset)
})

dflist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```r
jointdataset <-merge(knime.in, df, by.x = name, by.y ='Column 0')
```

Comment: hmm...don´t know why, but wasn´t working earlier with the same syntax. Thank you.